# what is wrong with this number to word convert?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var iWords = ['Zero', ' One', ' Two', ' Three', ' Four', ' Five', ' Six', ' Seven', ' Eight', ' Nine'];
var ePlace = ['Ten', ' Eleven', ' Twelve', ' Thirteen', ' Fourteen', ' Fifteen', ' Sixteen', ' Seventeen', ' Eighteen', ' Nineteen'];
var tensPlace = ['', ' Ten', ' Twenty', ' Thirty', ' Forty', ' Fifty', ' Sixty', ' Seventy', ' Eighty', ' Ninety'];
var inWords = [];
var numReversed, inWords, actualnum, i, j;
function test() {
    'use strict';
    if (actualnum[i] === 0) {
        inWords[j] = '';
    } else if (actualnum[i] === 1) {
        inWords[j] = ePlace[actualnum[i - 1]];
    } else {
        inWords[j] = tensPlace[actualnum[i]];
    }
}
function testSkill() {
    'use strict';
    var junkVal = document.getElementById('vals').value;
    junkVal = Math.floor(junkVal);
    var obStr = junkVal.toString();
    numReversed = obStr.split('');
    actualnum = numReversed.reverse();
    if (Number(junkVal) >= 0) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        window.alert('wrong Number cannot be converted');
        return false;
    }
    if (Number(junkVal) === 0) {
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = obStr + '' + ' Zero ';
        return false;
    }
    if (actualnum.length > 9) {
        window.alert('Oops!!!! the Number is too big to covertes');
        return false;
    }
    var iWordsLength = numReversed.length;
    var finalWord = '';
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < iWordsLength; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                if (actualnum[i] === '0' || actualnum[i + 1] === '1') {
                    inWords[j] = '';
                } else {
                    inWords[j] = iWords[actualnum[i]];
                }
                inWords[j] = inWords[j] + ' ';
                break;
            case 1:
                test();
                break;
            case 2:
                if (actualnum[i] === '0') {
                    inWords[j] = '';
                } else if (actualnum[i - 1] !== '0' && actualnum[i - 2] !== '0') {
                    inWords[j] = iWords[actualnum[i]] + ' Hundred and';
                } else {
                    inWords[j] = iWords[actualnum[i]] + ' Hundred';
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (actualnum[i] === '0' || actualnum[i + 1] === '1') {
                    inWords[j] = '';
                } else {
                    inWords[j] = iWords[actualnum[i]];
                }
                if (actualnum[i + 1] !== '0' || actualnum[i] > '0') {
                    inWords[j] = inWords[j] + ' Thousand';
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                test();
                break;
            case 5:
                if (actualnum[i] === '0' || actualnum[i + 1] === '1') {
                    inWords[j] = '';
                } else {
                    inWords[j] = iWords[actualnum[i]];
                }
                if (actualnum[i + 1] !== '0' || actualnum[i] > '0') {
                    inWords[j] = inWords[j] + ' Lakh';
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                test();
                break;
            case 7:
                if (actualnum[i] === '0' || actualnum[i + 1] === '1') {
                    inWords[j] = '';
                } else {
                    inWords[j] = iWords[actualnum[i]];
                }
                inWords[j] = inWords[j] + ' Crore';
                break;
            case 8:
                test();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    inWords.reverse();
    for (i = 0; i < inWords.length; i++) {
        finalWord += inWords[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = obStr + '  ' + finalWord;
}
</script>
```

Every time the user put numbers from 11-19 the out put is always "TEN". If i   put 15 it reads it as Ten. I have tried changing the loop but things just got worse. And some of my attempts don't even make any change even though it seems a big change and other keep making their own new problems.

Comment: In `test()`, you forget that `actualnum` is an array of characters, not of integers. Also, use parameters with `test()`, please!

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` operator in place of `===` in `function test()`

Note that, the identity **(===)** operator behaves identically to the equality **(==)** operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal. Since `actualnum` array if of type char, you are trying to compare it with number, hence condition is failing.

Comment: It also has error like if i type "12345" it reads it correctly like " Twelve Thousand Three Hundred and Forty Five" but then if I type a number very smaller(with out refreshing the browser)  like "2", it fails to say "Two".  it says something like "Five Forty Three Hundred and Thousand Two ". How can i fix that also.

Comment: @pepedeneke reset actualnum, i, j variables in testskill function

Comment: you mean like chenge them to something else?

Comment: @pepedeneke yes, something else is nothing but default values. For every new conversion, those variables should be refreshed. hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, It means a lot.